# Create an std::istream that simulates std::failbit or std::badbit after reading a few characters

Tags: c++

I would like to make an `istream` object result in `failbit` or `badbit` after at least five characters are successfully read. This is needed for writing a unit test to check that our code handles `failbit` and `badbit` correctly.

Here's a test function:

```cpp
bool test(std::istream &in) {
  int numchars = 0;
  while (in.good()) {
    int c = in.get();
    if (c == EOF) {
      std::cout << "eof encountered" << std::endl;
      return false;
    }
    std::cerr << "read: " << static_cast<char>(c) << std::endl;
    numchars++;
  }

  if (numchars < 5) {
    std::cout << "too few characters read" << std::endl;
    return false;
  }

  std::cout << "hooray" << std::endl;
  return true;
}
```

We can't change the `test` function.

It should return `true` and print out `hooray`.

Here are some things that don't work:

```cpp
  std::stringstream ss("This is a test string.");
  ss.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
  test(ss); // returns false, prints out `too few characters read`
```

```cpp
  std::stringstream ss("This is a test string.");
  test(ss); // returns false, prints out `eof encountered`
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Remy Lebeau's hint, I managed to get it working:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class FailBuffer : public std::streambuf {
public:
  FailBuffer(std::streambuf *original_buf, std::streamsize n)
      : original_buf(original_buf), chars_left(n) {}
  std::istream *parent;
  char ch; // single-byte buffer

protected:
  virtual int underflow() override {
    // based on example at
    // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/underflow
    const traits_type::int_type i = original_buf->sbumpc();
    if (!traits_type::eq_int_type(i, traits_type::eof())) {
      ch = traits_type::to_char_type(i);
      setg(&ch, &ch, &ch + 1); // make one read position available
    }
    chars_left--;
    if (chars_left <= 0) {
      parent->setstate(std::ios::failbit);
    }
    return i;
  }

private:
  std::streambuf *original_buf;
  std::streamsize chars_left;
};

class FailStream : public std::istream {
public:
  FailStream(std::istream &original_stream, std::streamsize n)
      : std::istream(&fail_buffer), fail_buffer(original_stream.rdbuf(), n) {
    fail_buffer.parent = this;
  }

private:
  FailBuffer fail_buffer;
};

bool test(std::istream &in) {
  int numchars = 0;
  while (in.good()) {
    int c = in.get();
    if (c == EOF) {
      std::cout << "eof encountered" << std::endl;
      return false;
    }
    std::cerr << "read: " << static_cast<char>(c) << std::endl;
    numchars++;
  }

  if (numchars < 5) {
    std::cout << "too few characters read" << std::endl;
    return false;
  }

  std::cout << "hooray" << std::endl;
  return true;
}

int main() {
  std::istringstream testss("hello world");
  FailStream cfis(testss, 5);
  test(cfis);
}
```

Valgrind verifies it runs without memory issues.

```
g++ -Og -g -o streamtest streamtest.cc; and valgrind ./streamtest
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom class that is derived from [`std::streambuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf) and overrides its `virtual` methods to simulate the conditions you want (ie, to return a read error after N characters have been read).

Then, create an instance of [`std::istream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream), giving its constructor a pointer to an instance of your custom `streambuf` class.